# Add to Apache logfile when user leaves webpage

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I want to time how long a visitor spends on each page of my website by downloading and analysing the "ex" log file created daily by Apache in the logfiles folder.

I can do this when they move from one page to another but if someone visits the homepage and then leaves I have no idea how long they spent on it.

Could I somehow use Javascript's OnBeforeUnload event to request a file from the server, which would then appear in the log?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you want to request a file from the server. You could just request a blank page:

```
$(window).unload( function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/url/to/blank/page'
    });
}
```